# GridView Layout android:horizontalSpacing is not working

Tags: android, grid

I am using android:horizontalSpacing attribute in my GridView layout to give horizontal spacing between two columns. But nothing getting change only it give space between the vertical columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="7" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

This is the above code but i don't understand what is the actual mistake i am doing. You can see in above picture that , there are only black vertical lines but i also want horizontal black lines.

Please help me out , suggest me some solution.